# How can I change the C++ compiler in Matlab over OSX

Tags: c++, matlab, gcc

When I type "`mex -setup C++`"

It returns :

```
MEX configured to use 'Xcode Clang++' for C++ language compilation.
```

How can I set it to my `gcc-5` located at `/usr/local/bin/gcc-5`?

Comment: That's explained quite clearly in the MathWorks documentation. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/changing-default-compiler.html Did you read that? If you did, what didn't work?

Comment: @CST-Link I have `tried:copyfile(fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','examples','refbook','timestwo.c'),'.','f')` and then `mex -v GCC='/usr/bin/gcc-5' timestwo.c` And it still uses clang

Comment: Do you have an actual compiler there, or is just a leftover folder from a previous installation? Did you try to compile with it from `bash`, for example? If yes, does it get displayed in the list of available compilers, when you type `mex -setup C++`? If no, are you sure is installed correctly? If yes, did you follow the documentation instructions about the `varname` (search in the page linked before this keyword to see what I mean). If yes, are you sure that `/usr/local/bin/gcc-5` (as you wrote in your post) and `/usr/bin/gcc-5` (as you wrote in your comment above) are the same thing?

Comment: It exits over there indeed! If I type `mex -setup C++` it directly outputs that: `MEX configured to use 'Xcode Clang++' for C++ language compilation.`  And I don't know how can I set `varname`. There is only a gcc-5 in `/usr/local/bin` but not `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Xcode is the [only supported](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2016a/index.html?sec=maci64) C/C++ 'compiler' on OSX.

Comment: Xcode isn't really a compiler – the download does include clang though. Just because it's the the only "supported" system doesn't mean that one can't use others.